# Excel - Getting the Top 5 data of a column and their matching title but produces duplicates

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I am developing a web application made using PHP (withh CodeIgniter as the framework) that should produce an excel file report as as summary of data.

I am using PHPSpreadsheet as a library to generate the .xlsx file and everything is successful.

[image: Raw Data]

I was able to display in a certain range of cell the top 5 values of a column ie. Top 5 **Publications** that has the most number of **Articles**.

With the use of the code `=LARGE(ColumnOfTheDataRange , NumeralValue)` -- I was able to get the top 5 of what I wanted

[image: Top 5]

Then, on the left side of these top 5 data, I need to display the matching **Publication Names / Publications**. I was able to do it with the function `=INDEX(PublicationNamesCellRange, MATCH(CellOfTheMatchingData, ColumnOfTheDataCellRange, 0))`

[image: Publication Names]

Now, kindly notice that there are multiple article counts **54** in the top 5 data column (right), which should belong to 2 different **Publications**. The problem is, what code or technique should I use to produce the unique Publication Name so that it won't repeat the Publication Name **E** because in the original excel file, the Publication Name **E** is the first one that has the matching data of **54**?

Comment: There are a couple of posts on here that show solutions for this - I made use of them, so have a search. Even if you don’t find them you can look at large() and aggregate() but aggregate() is excel version dependant.

Comment: hello sir @SolarMike, good day! Before posting this, I made sure that there's no available solution because I've kept on looking for one for the past 3 days. If there is, may you kindly give me the link please? or tag this post as duplicate?

As for your tip regarding the `aggregate()` function, will be looking for it, thank you very much for the idea!

Comment: I'm surprised you have not found relevant posts, as I made clear that is how I found my solution...

Comment: And why not just use a Pivot Table?

Comment: Hello @MichalRosa good day! make a Pivot Table of those 2 where I concat them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up using, edit to your situation.

[image]

Comment: hello sir! thank you so much for this, still testing though, may I know what is the purpose of `ROW($1:$30)` code in your example?

Comment: I've tested some more stuff, still confused with the purpose of `ROW($1:$30)`, should it be static sir?

Comment: hellosir @SolarMike some of the cells are producing an error message `#NUM!`

Comment: Then you must have one of the ranges or arguments incorrect, this works on 5 different sets of data in my real sheet, and it works in that example as I had to reset the names.

Comment: Brilliant! tested everything and made adjustments in the `ROW($1:$30)` part, change the **$30** according to the maximum or highest cell address to be included

for example the range of your column reaches **E99** then adjust the code to `ROW($1:$99)` then I'm able to fetch the distinct publication names, no more duplicates! thank you very much for this sir @SolarMike :)

Comment: This is my final code `=INDEX($E$4:$E$200,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$200) / ($J$4:$J$200=M4), COUNTIF($M$4:M4, M4)))` works like a charm! Again, thank you very much sir @SolarMike

Comment: additional question sir @SolarMike, might as well ask this from you since you're experienced with this. When I applied the function / code I have mentioned above directly to the excel file, I don't encounter any problem, but when placed it in my php code while using the PHPSpreadsheet library, it says the following error `Wrong number of arguments for INDEX() function: 5 given, between 1 and 4 expected' `. Do you have any idea about this, sir?

Comment: Sounds like you have lost a bracket or have a "," in the wrong place. BUt php may not like the way excel uses index...

Comment: sir @SolarMike, I have no extra "," in the code / script, it's the exact code placed in the Formula Bar

Comment: Think about " But php may not like the way excel uses index.." or AGGREGATE()... as I suggested to your question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56018814/4961700

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192996/discussion-between-jueviole17-and-solar-mike).