# PHPSpreadsheet generates an error "Wrong number of arguments for INDEX() function: 5 given, between 1 and 4 expected"

Tags: php, excel, laravel, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I tried to enter the following code in my excel formula bar directly
`=INDEX($E$4:$E$132,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$30) / ($J$4:$J$132=M4), COUNTIF($M$4:M4, M4)))` and works perfectly fine (the left column on the pic below).

[image: pic]

But if I'm using my web application to generate an excel report file (PHP, using CodeIgniter and Laravel). It displays an error "**'Wrong number of arguments for INDEX() function: 5 given, between 1 and 4 expected'**"

Here's my sample code snippet:

```
$code = "=INDEX(\$E\$4:\$E\$$occurance, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(\$1:\$$occurance) / (\$J\$4:\$J\$$occurance=M$top_cell), COUNTIF(\$M\$4:M$top_cell, M$top_cell)))";
$ews2->setCellValue("L$top_cell", $code);
```

I also have tried to use the **setValueExplicit** method but causes the excel file to NOT precalculate the code, it reads the code as a *string*

```
$ews2->setCellValueExplicit("L$top_cell", $code, DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

**NOTE** TYPE_STRING is provided because if TYPE_FORMULA is also used, the same output mentioned at the top occurs

Here's what it looks like using the **setCellValueExplicit**

[image: Precoded from PHP]
May I know the right solution or quick fix for this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does the version of PhP, codeigniter or Laravel support aggregate() ? if they don't or one of them does not then it would think that index() has too many arguments.

Comment: My CodeIgniter app has PHP version 5.6, while my Laravel app has PHP version 7.2 sir, do you think it's with the PHP version?

Comment: I don't have any of those to check so you need to check, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: What do you get when you echo $code?

Comment: hello @TimBrownlaw, I have other variables there such as the `$occurance` and `$top_cell` that computes on what cell should be the reference of the computation, they just display numbers, the same as the formula at the top

Comment: Well when you get an error like you have reported, you go back and view the generated string that is causing it and see why. Which is why I asked.

Comment: I already found the error sir, the PhpSpreadsheet library that I am using to generate the excel file prohibits the usage of complex codes and aggregated functions, so I used another code that does not use any Aggregate function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the PHPSpreadsheet library for PHP is yet to allow the usage of the `AGGREGATE()` and complicated formulas/functions, so I had found another way around

By using this excel code

`=INDEX(E$2:E$38,IF(M4=M3,MATCH(L3,E$2:E$38,0),0)+MATCH(M4,OFFSET(J$2,IF(M4=M3,MATCH(L3,E$2:E$38,0),0),0,COUNT(J$2:J$38)-IF(M4=M3,MATCH(L3,E$2:E$38,0),0),1),0))`

I was able to traverse through my entire range and make sure that no duplicate publication names would appear

This is in relation with the my other question -> [Excel - Getting the 2nd or nth matched string from your corresponding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034507/excel-getting-the-2nd-or-nth-matched-string-from-your-corresponding-data)