# finding associated cell's for AGGREGATE formula to determine top differences of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i'm using an AGGREGATE formula in excel in order to get the top 5 deference of a column of data but i don't know  how to get the cell addresses that produced the number.

with this formula i'm able to get the top 5 differences right in the cell i want without any "help column"

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,B$3:B$4001-B$2:B$4000,ROWS(F$2:F2))
```

i tried to get a reference using ADDRESS and INDEX but could not figure it out.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016036/4961700

Comment: it kinda have a help column and the data that the formula is matching does exist as a number ... in my case it's the differences between cells and there is no help column.