# Return Multiple Unique Matches in Excel without Array Formula

Tags: excel, list, unique, array-formulas

Given an Excel table of shape

```
Col. A   Col B   Col. C   Col. D   Col. E
x        2       x        2        3
x        3       y        7
y        7       z        -5
x        2
z        -5
```

I want to return the first unique hit in Column B for argument "x" in Column D,
the second unique hit in Column B for argument "x" in Column E and so forth.

The formula I'm currently using in cell D1 for this is

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C1:C1,$B$1:$B$5)+($A$1:$A$5<>$C1),0)),"")}`

which is working.

The problem I'm having is that since this is an array formula and since I'm analyzing a decent amount of data computation time for my sheet is too high.

Is there an alternative for this functionality avoiding an array formula?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016036/4961700

Comment: @Harun24HR version 2102

Comment: If you can use Filter and Unique it would still be an array formula, but might be faster.

Comment: @SolarMike I tried to replicate the formula from your post and was unsuccessful. I'm not entirely sure if this is the same problem.

Comment: So edit it to match your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't got time to test this properly, but if you have Excel 365 you can use a single formula per row and it may be faster:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B10,A1:A10=C1)))
```

in D1.

*EDIT*

To pull the formula down, you need static references as OP has pointed out. Probably should check for empty cells in column C as well, so formula becomes:

```
=IF(C1="","",TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$1:B$10,A$1:A$10=C1))))
```

Comment: This is working. Only thing I had to edit is using static references b$1:b$10, a$1:a$10.

Comment: Yes, I realised this later as well - will edit my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to provide an additional comment on computation time: As expected, this is much faster than using my original array formula.

Comment: is it possible to return the output into an array that is stored in one cell? I have to create a lot of Columns to not get a "SPILL!" error.

Comment: Yes, you could return it in one cell with separators like 2,3,4 =IF(C1="","",TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(FILTER(B$1:B$10,A$1:A$10=C1))))