# Using single formula to list unique items, count and sort numerically by descending order and then alphabetically for items with same count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

As title says I need to use a single formula for listing unique items from raw list in a column, count them and sort them numerically by descending order and then alphabetically for items with same count, finally also excluding some words like "ITEMS".

This should help understand:
[image]

Is this doable? I did this with a complicated formula for the sorting on a left column then on the righ each cell with a COUNT formula but it's not elegant, not efficient and for some reason some items were not counted correctly. I tried combinations of QUERY, UNIQUE, ARRAYFORMULA, COUNT etc but can't get it to work like I want.

Dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hjkNMV3eHOBxiF9ENLZBYdJfnY-0bLDMJSnZTBFeG0/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone provide any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: You can't tag both google sheets and Excel for this. They follow different logic, especially on array-formulas. Please untag what's not desired.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016036/4961700

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On google-sheet you can use `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A4:A,"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) DESC label count(A) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. I was thinking that you would have to order by count(A) desc, then A, but I think what happens is that group by already sorts into alphabetical order and any further sorting preserves the alphabetical order where there are ties on the other sort key.

Comment: Hey @Harun24hr this is good. Just one thing how do I remove "ITEMS"? You solved it by starting the range at row 4. The reason why I asked about removing words is that there will be a bunch of undeisirable items which I need to remove not just titles and headers. I should have explained better. I tried now with your formula SUBSTITUTE but then it does not creat the list and only "Apple" appears. ´´´=QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(B3:B,"ITEMS",""),"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) DESC label count(Col1) ''")´´´

Comment: Solved it! 
```=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(B3:B,"ITEMS","")),"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) DESC label count(Col1) ''")```  Thanks everyone!

Comment: To solve that issue one can use `matches()`. For example: `=QUERY(B3:B,"Select B, count(B) where B matches '^(?!ITEMS$).+' group by B order by count(B) DESC label count(B) ''")`. In general, extend the pattern with alternations: `^(?!(?:ExcludeA|ExcludeB|ExcludeC)$).+` @Verminous

Comment: Yes that is a better solution. Thank you. @JvdV

Comment: @Harun24hr Do you know if your solution can be applied to a situation where one needs to use a time period for the listing? I posted a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619217/list-unique-items-count-and-sort-numerically-by-descending-order-and-combine-w/72620657?noredirect=1#comment128290143_72620657

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it's Excel you're looking for, but this will work in Excel (Office 365):

```
=LET(a,B4:B39,
     u,UNIQUE(a),
     c,COUNTIF(a,u),
SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},u,c),{2,1},{-1,1}))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent tips for excel users.