# Find the top 3 categories per month

Tags: excel, xlookup

I have a spreadsheet where I have a pivot that breaks down the topic of contact on the Rows and the volume per month in the columns. I need to take this pivot and display the top 3 reasons for contact for each month, regardless of when the pivot changes based on the original raw data.

I have tried many different formulas and I feel like I'm making this harder than it has to be but I can't figure it out. The problem is that it is counting only the first "contact topic" when there are two different topics that tied in volume. So for example: topic "Battery Issue" and topic "Returns" each have 10 tickets in January. When I use these formulas, it will return "Battery Issue" as #2 and #3, instead of "Returns" as #3.

What am I doing wrong?

Formulas I have tried...

=XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(LARGE(B$5:B$63,1),FALSE,FALSE),B$5:B$63,$A$5:$A$63)

=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($A$5:$A$64,A$5:B$64=T2),COUNTIFS(T$2:$T2,T2)),0)

Both of these work perfectly as long as each contact topic had different totals each month. I've tried a few variants of XLOOKUP with UNIQUE and LARGE; I've tried Sorting, Ranking, Indexing, etc.

Column B is January volume in my pivot and column A is the contact topic in the pivot. T2 is January's highest volume, just the number.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this out and edit to suit, it it helps give it a vote : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016036/4961700 I Use it to check absences dealing with duplicates etc